# How Can I Make My Popup Window Appear on Top of All Other Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the JSFiddle example, if you click one the element boxes (not on the letter itself), a popup window opens that displays more information about the element. If one of the top elements are clicked (Hydrogen, for example), the popup is hidden behind the breadcrumb and header elements, and I'd like the popup to be on top of all other elements so the information can be displayed.

I've tried using the obvious z-index for layering, and tried to make sure I was using it correctly, but my popup is still obscurred by the top two divs. I thought code that appears beneath other code was rendered on top anyway?

Here is my JSFiddle example. Can anybody help me with this one?
https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/chqpg4dt/8/

'''

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">      
       <div class="vNumber" id="v1"><h6>1</h6></div>
<!-- HYDROGEN -->
       <div class="p-1 box reactiveNonMetals popup" id="Hydrogen" onClick="elemHydrogen()">
       <span class="popuptext" id="popup-hydrogen">
        Element: <span class="white"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen" onClick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow',
                                   `toolbar=no,
                                    location=no,
                                    status=no,
                                    menubar=no,
                                    scrollbars=yes,
                                    resizable=yes,
                                    width=750px,
                                    height=500px`);
 return false;" class="type1">Hydrogen</a></span><br>
        Series: <span class="white">Reactive Nonmetals</span><br>
        Atomic Number: <span class="white">1</span><br>
        Energy Levels: <span class="white">1</span><br>
        Atomic Weight: <span class="white">1.008 u</span><br>
        Electronegativity: <span class="white">2.20</span><br>
        Melting Point: <span class="white">259.1&#176; C</span><br>
        Boiling Point: <span class="white">-252.9&#176; C</span><br>
        Electron Affinity: <span class="white">72.8 kJ/mol</span><br>
        Ionization: <span class="white">1,312.0 kJ/mol</span><br>
        Radius Calculated: <span class="white">53 pm</span><br>
        Hardness, Brinell: <span class="white">N/A MPa</span><br>
        Modulus, Bulk: <span class="white">N/A GPa</span><br>
        Conductivity, Thermal: <span class="white">0.1805 W/mK</span><br>
        Heat, Specific: <span class="white">14,300 J/kgK</span><br>
        Abundance, Universe: <span class="white">75%</span><br>
        Discovered: <span class="white">1766</span></span>
        <h6 class="atomicNumber">1</h6>
        <h6 class="energyLevels">1</h6>
        <h6 class="element"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rdmpx39PRk" target="blank" class="gas">H</a></h6>
        <h6 class="commonName">Hydrogen</h6>
        <h6 class="atomicWeight">1.008</h6>
       </div><!-- CLOSES HYDROGEN -->
```

'''

Here's a link to the actual page - https://www.sanjosecoder.com/periodic-table.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your .fixed-top class has a z-index of 1030 and your popup show has a z-index of 999 so thats your problem there... Inspect your code in devTools and change the z-index values there... so you can see exactly where to change values... in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, loomy - the z-index of 1030 was a mistake, but thank you for pointing it out. Even if I correct that value for the .fixed-top and .popup classes, I can't get the popup to appear on top.

I've tried positioning the obscurring two top header divs with a lower z-index value to no avail.